# error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type

Tags: c

Looked through many other SO posts related to this, but none were able to help me. So, I have the following structs defined:

```
 typedef struct
    {
    int created;
    double data;
    int timeLeft;
    int destination;
}dataPacket;

typedef struct
{
    dataPacket *array;
    int currIndex;
    int firstIndex;
    int nextTick;
    int maxLength;
    int length;
    int stime;
    int total;


}packetBuffer;

typedef struct{
    int mac;
    struct wire *lconnection;
    struct wire *rconnection;
    int numRecieved;
    struct packetBuffer *buffer;
    int i;
    int backoff;
}node;

typedef struct{
    float length;
    float speed;
    int busy;
    struct dataPacket *currPacket;
    struct node *lnode;
    struct node *rnode;
}wire;
```

And then I'm trying to use the following function:

```
    int sendPacket(node *n, int tick)
{
    if(n->buffer->length > 0)
    {
        if(n->backoff <= 0)
        {
            if (n->lconnection->busy != 0 || n->lconnection->busy != 0)
            {
                n->i++;
                n->backoff = (512/W * genrand()*(pow(2,n->i)-1))/TICK_LENGTH;
            }
            else
            {
                n->lconnection->busy = 1;
                n->rconnection->busy = 1;
                n->lconnection->currPacket = n->buffer[n->buffer->currIndex];
                n->rconnection->currPacket = n->buffer[n->buffer->currIndex];
            }
        }
        else
        {
            n->backoff--;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting the error described in the title everytime I try to access a member of buffer, lconnection, or rconnection.

Comment: `if (n->lconnection->busy != 0 || n->lconnection->busy != 0)`... why have an `or` statement with identical conditions?

Comment: @d0rmLife: Presumably the RHS should refer to `rconnection`

Comment: @KeithThompson ...no doubt...! ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
struct packetBuffer *buffer;
```

You've defined a type `packetBuffer` (a typedef for an otherwise anonymous struct).

You haven't defined `struct packetBuffer`.

In the absence of an existing type `struct packetBuffer`, the compiler treats it as an incomplete type, assuming that you'll complete it later. The declaration

```
struct packetBuffer *buffer;
```

is perfectly legal, but you can't dereference `buffer` unless the type `struct packetBuffer` is visible.

Just drop the `struct` keyword.

(My personal preference is to drop the `typedef` and consistently refer to struct types as `struct whatever`, but that's a matter of style and taste.)

Answer (score 1):

The following:

`typedef struct {
   int x;
   char *y;
   ...
} my_struct;`

creates an identifier for an anonymous structure.  In order, for a structure to refer to an instance of itself, it must not be "anonymous":

```
typedef struct my_struct {
    int x;
    char *y;
    struct my_struct *link
    ....
} my_struct_t;
```

This means that `my_struct_t` is now the type `struct my_struct` and not just an anonymous struct.  Also, note that `struct my_struct` can be used within its own structure definition.  That is not possible with anonymous structs.

As a final complication, the `my_struct` in `struct my_struct` is in a differenct "namespace" than the `my_struct_t`.  This is sometimes used to to simplify (or confuse) things in code like this:

```
typedef struct my_struct {
    int x;
    char *y;
    struct my_struct *link
    ....
} my_struct;
```

Now I can use `my_struct` anywhere in my code instead of `struct my_struct`.

Finally, you could separate the typedef from the structure definition to achieve the same effect:

```
struct my_struct {
    int x;
    char *y;
    struct my_struct *link;
    ....
};
typedef struct my_struct my_struct;
```

As noted in David R.Hanson's **C Interfaces and Implementations**, "This definition is legal because structure, union, and enumeration tags occupy a same name space that is separate from the space for variables, functions, and type names."